# Incompatiblity of Adobe font and xpinyin package?

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, xpinyin

One of font package (i.e. Adobe Garamond Pro) is not compatible with vowels encoding using xpinyin package. Can I exclude these fonts?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK,xpinyin}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} %%problematic with pinyin
\begin{document}
  \xpinyin*{学而不思则罔}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am assuming that you understand Chinese, so I will copy and paste the following description in the user manual of `xpinyin`: `设置拼音的字体，缺省值是 \normalfont，即以正文西文字体相同。为了保证拼音能正确输出，最好选用收字量较大的西文字体`, which roughly translates to `The font for pīnyīn is the same as the Latin main font. To guarantee correct output of pīnyīn, better choose a Latin font which contains a lot of glyphs` So clearly `Adobe Garamond Pro` is *NOT* suitable for pīnyīn here.

Comment: For a comprehensive discussion on pīnyīn, I suggest [this article](https://thetype.com/2017/08/11606/) by Type is Beautiful. The article (in Chinese, simplified and traditional versions available) also gives suggestions on the font choice for pīnyīn.

Comment: @HenriMenke Deleting my answer: Huh. For whatever reason, when Adobe’s site gives me the ability to type in a font sample for Adobe Garamond Pro, and I enter that combination, it works. Is that a newer version of the font, or is the website giving inaccurate information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe Garamond does not encode `ǎ` (U+01CE LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CARON) and is also missing `̌` (U+030C COMBINING CARON).  I can think of two solutions:

1. Use a different font.  There are plenty of nice Garamond-derived typefaces out there which do not have such spotty encoding (and are non-commercial!).

   ```
   \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{xeCJK,xpinyin}
   \setmainfont{EB Garamond}
   \begin{document}
     \xpinyin*{学而不思则罔}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{xeCJK,xpinyin}
   \setmainfont{Cormorant Garamond}
   \begin{document}
     \xpinyin*{学而不思则罔}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Remap `ǎ` (U+01CE LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CARON) to something else.  Here I map it to just the regular `a` (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A).  The mapping below is derived from the standard `tex-text` mapping.

   **`acaron.map`**

   ```
   LHSName "acaron"
   RHSName "a"
   pass(Unicode)
   ; replace acaron with a
   U+01CE > U+0061 ;
   ; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
   U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
   U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

   U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
   U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
   U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

   U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
   U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

   U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
   U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question
   ```

   The I compile the mapping using the TECkit tool.

   ```
   teckit_compile -u acaron.map -o acaron.tec
   ```

   Afterwards it can be used in XeLaTeX.

   ```
   \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{xeCJK,xpinyin}
   \setmainfont[Mapping=acaron]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
   \begin{document}
     \xpinyin*{学而不思则罔}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   You could also choose the mapping `U+01CE > U+02C7 U+0061 ;`, i.e. caron followed by a, which then renders as

   [image]

   That's not pretty but at least preserves the meaning.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `EB Garamond`! However, as a native speaker, I disagree with the last solution with `U+01CE > U+02C7 U+0061 ;`. A more acceptable solution would be `wang3` with the `3` denoting the tone, while `wang` (with only the regular `a`) would be utterly wrong. ;-)